# Java client for streaming Data with Spring Boot using StreamingResponseBody

Tags: spring, streaming

A spring rest endpoint to stream data seems to be programmed rather straigthforward using a `StreamingResponseBody` ([example](https://medium.com/swlh/streaming-data-with-spring-boot-restful-web-service-87522511c071)). Could anybody point me to a resource on how to write a client in java (another spring app)?

Answer (score 0):

You must consume the data as any other web resource, for example with spring :

```
String value = new RestTemplate().getForObject("https://someuri.com", String.class);
```